# Change the color of the bar of histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to print a Histogram but I need all the values which is bigger than a specific value(250 for example) to be in orange.

The output is:
[image]

and I need it to be something like that :
[image]
Any Help,
This is the code:

```
    fh = figure;
    hist(PZ);
    saveas(fh, strcat('Figures\window), 'jpg')
    close(fh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is using [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) to plot your data, but in this case you are limited to the colors it provides, which are: `'b' | 'r' | 'g' | 'c' | 'm' | 'y' | 'k' | 'w'`. Here's a sample code to do that:

```
%// Generate data
data = randn(2000,1);
bins = -5:5;
[N,X] = hist(data,bins);
%% //Color by count
LIMIT_VAL = 500;
figure();
bar(X,N,'b');hold on;
bar(X,N.*(N<LIMIT_VAL),'r'); hold off;
%% //Color by bin position
LIMIT_VAL = 2;
figure();
bar(X,N,'b');hold on;
bar(X(abs(X)>=LIMIT_VAL),N(abs(X)>=LIMIT_VAL),'r'); hold off;
```

Another way is by modifying the patch color as was mentioned by @lakesh.

Comment: I tried the code but it colors the data that is more than 500 in y axis(count) but need to color the data which is greater that 500 for example in the x axis not y axis.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the data into two groups.Values greater than 250 and values lesser than 250. Both in absolute values.

Then, can you this code to set the color of histogram to be different

```
hist(data1);
hold on;
hist(data2);
h = findobj(gca,’Type’,’patch’);
display(h) 
set(h(1),’FaceColor’,’b’,’EdgeColor’,’k’);
set(h(2),’FaceColor’,rgb('orange'),’EdgeColor’,’k’);
```